# Solid State Relay operation

Tags: current, solid-state-relay

A solid state relay specifies a trigger current of "7.5mA/12V". How much current does it draw at 5V?

[This is the relay.](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13015) I'm controlling it with an Arduino which has a maximum current draw of 40 mA per pin. Am I correct in calculating it multiplying 7.5 by 12 then dividing by 5 (the new voltage)? That gives me 18 mA, well within the limits of the Arduino pin - is it really that simple, or am I missing something important?

Comment: A relay is not a constant power device, it will not draw more current at lower voltage.  In fact it may not trigger at all at 5V if it's specified as a 12V relay.

Comment: @JohnD: the linked datasheet shows that it is an SSR, rated for 3 - 32 volt input.

Comment: @PeterBennett Thanks, Peter, I was in a hurry hence the comment vs. an answer.  You're correct, so the relay should work at 5V, but it's still not a constant power device so current shouldn't be MORE than the current at 12V.  What it will actually be really depends on the internal circuitry.

Comment: Looks like there's internal current limiting circuitry inside the SSR.  The control side works from 3-32VDC.  If the Arduino pin can handle 40 mA then that is enough to drive the SSR input @ 5VDC directly without damage.  The datasheet even says CMOS IC or TTL compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a comparable "hockey puck" SSR handy.  It also has the 3V to 32V input, although it's a different  model ([ESR5102401000Z](http://www.jameco.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Product_10001_10001_162342_-1)).  I made some quick measurements.

[image]

I was curious how these solid state relays (SSR) manage to accept a control voltage with a fairly wide range: from 3V to 32V.  Of course, the datasheets for these "hockey puck" SSR don't provide the details about the input side.  I can think of 3 schemes.  Different models of SSRs may use different schemes.

#### Current limiting resistor

The LED and resistor are such that the current is low enough at 32V not to destroy the LED, but still high enough at +3V to activate the relay.  In this arrangement, the input current will *increase linearly* with input voltage.

#### Series current limiter (active)

The input current *shouldn't vary much* with input voltage.  The constant current source may be more or less stiff.  The plot in [Spehro's answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/180692/7036) suggests a series constant current regulator in his SSR.

#### Shunt current limiter (active)

The input current will *increase linearly* with input voltage.  Excess current shunted around the LED, but still drawn from the input.  Here's an example of what a shunt current limiter may look like ([source](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/HBD855-D.PDF)).

[image]

Comment: If there is one common factor in all these possibilities it is that the current should be <= 7.5mA at 5V. Until someone comes up with one that uses a SMPS constant power regulator...

Comment: Load is missing in the triac side?

Answer (score 2):

It will draw about the same current at 5V. The IR LED used in the SSR requires a certain amount of current to switch reliably and the typical input circuit for a 3-32V input SSR is a simple constant-current regulator made with discrete BJTs.

Here is [another manufacturer](http://www.crydom.com/en/products/catalog/s_1.pdf)'s graph showing input current vs. voltage:

[image]

Of course this is just an educated guess on my part as the datasheet is characteristically inscrutable and/or mute on the point (as well as lacking safety agency approval markings), but every similar SSR I've seen works similarly to this.

Comment: Apparently, not all SSRs regulate the input current like that.  Have a look at [my answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/180695/7036) in this thread.

Comment: Well, nothing beats measurements! +1 to you. That one could also meet the datasheet spec for the OP's SSR>

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation is wrong - it should be 7.5 * (5/12), as we would expect a lower current with a lower voltage if there is just a resistor in series with the LEDs..

However, the datasheet shows an "input circuit" between the input terminals and the LEDs, so there may be something more than just a resistor in series with the LED - perhaps a constant current circuit, so the LEDs won't get excessive current with a 32 volt input.

I'd guess the current at 5 volts might be a little less than 7.5 mA, but probably not more than 7.5 mA.  The only way to be sure is to measure it.

Comment: perhaps the input circuit is some sort of current-sourcing buck regulator. infrared LEDs need less than 1V to operate.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [Spehro Pefhany's answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/180692/7036).  The datasheet shows an equivalent circuit model for the input side of the of the SSR.  Have a look at the diagram on the right for DC control.  You will see a current limiter in series with the input pin (+DC Pin 3).

[image]